# What's wrong with this SubRouting?

Tags: routes, react-router-dom, router

I'm learning about 'react router dome' and this is my blogging project using it.

Main Routing Page - **app.js**

```
          <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
          <Route exact path="/post/personal" component={PersonalPage} />
          <Route exact path="/post/something" component={SomethingPage} />
          <Route exact path="/post/javascript" component={JavascriptPage} />
          <Route exact path="/post/react" component={ReactPage} />
 <Route
            render={() => (
              <div
                style={{
                  padding: "20px",
                  width: "280px",
                  margin: "0 auto",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                }}
              >
                Worng Page found
              </div>
            )}
          />
```

**/post/personal - PersonalPage**

```
   <Link className="more" to={`/post/personal/${value._id}`}>
          Click&gt;
        </Link>
      
        <Route
          exact
          path={`/post/personal/:postId`}
          component={PersonalDetailPage}
        />
```

My idea is that if i push the Click Link button, i go inside Route [PersonalDetailPage].
but my code is not working, and PErsonalDetailPage is not show up

The screen shows only 'wrong page found'.

But if you write the code this way, it works fine.

**app.js**

```
<Route exact path ="/post/personal/:postId
```

I want to use subRouting without using up routing on the main page, app.js.
How can I do?
plz help me god programmer friend !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your Routing is that you are defining exact attribute on all your top level routes.Now when you do that the nested routes cannot render because the parent route doesn't match the entire path.

For instance if you visit `/post/personal/5`, the path `/post/personal` rendering `PersonalPage` component exactly doesn't match with it and since PersonalPage doesn't re-render, none of its subroutes are being matched

The solution to this is to use [**Switch**](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component instead of using exact attributes and define your routes in the order so that prefix path are towards the end

```
 <Switch>
      <Route  path="/post/personal" component={PersonalPage} />
      <Route  path="/post/something" component={SomethingPage} />
      <Route  path="/post/javascript" component={JavascriptPage} />
      <Route  path="/post/react" component={ReactPage} />
      <Route
        render={() => (
          <div
            style={{
              padding: "20px",
              width: "280px",
              margin: "0 auto",
              fontWeight: "bold",
            }}
          >
            Worng Page found
          </div>
        )}
      />
     <Route  path="/" component={LandingPage} />
 </Switch>
```

**P.S.** Switch component renders the first matched route amongst its children

Comment: It was simple. Thank you for your kind explanation.